# Read JTable data back to XML

Tags: xml, jtable

I am working on the application where I have to showcase the XML into JTable format to user. User can edit the data and same data should be saved back as the XML file again. So far I am able to show the XML data in JTable format. However I dont know how to retrieve the edited JTable data back to XML.

Can someone please help??

Answer (score 1):

The data displayed by a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) *view* is contained in the table's *model*.

```
JTable table = new JTable(…);
TableModel model = table.getModel();
// loop though the model using getValueAt()
```

> How can I put the data in XML structure.

Use [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html), which "provides methods for unmarshalling (reading) XML instance documents into Java content trees, and then marshalling (writing) Java content trees back into XML instance documents." More examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjava%5D%20%5Bxml%5D%20marshall).

Comment: Even if I loop through the model, how can I put the data in XML structure. It can be nested XML, may contain attributes also.

Comment: I've elaborated above.

Comment: Thanks for for solution. But still I am not able to solve the problem. Can you please explain with sample code?

Comment: I have nothing better than the tutorial examples, which are are cited [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/examples.html).